# Retrieve XML schema input/output types for given operation from WSDL

Tags: web-services, wsdl, cxf

What is the best way to programatically obtain the XML schema input/output types for a specific operation defined in a WSDL file.

The reason I need this is to be able, in tooling, be able to transform to the required type before the web-service is invoked.

thanks!